# (PHP - SQL) My php like-counter doesn't work properly

Tags: php, sql, database, counter, dao

I'm currently making a website about sauces where you can 'like' a sauce if you like it.

This is what happens right now:

https://giphy.com/gifs/website-query-g0jZqj4A0g3EzDyQod

When I go to the website and I click on a flame (the like button), nothing happens. When I press for the second time, it counts the like how it should.

This is my code with the query:

```
<?php    
require_once( __DIR__ . '/DAO.php');

class insertVoteDAO1 extends DAO {

  public function insertVote1() {
      $sql = "UPDATE ic_items SET flames = flames+1 WHERE id=1";
      $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      }
}
?>
```

This is the code in my collection.php:

```
<?php
   require_once( __DIR__ . '/dao/insertVoteDAO1.php');
   $voteDAO1 = new insertVoteDAO1();
?>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['action1']) == 'insertVote1') {
    $insertedVote = $voteDAO1->insertVote1();
   }
 ?>
```

This is the query to get the info of the sauce:

```
<?php

require_once( __DIR__ . '/DAO.php');

class GetInfoDAO extends DAO {

  public function selectAllTheInfo(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ic_items";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
}
?>
```

This is the code to get the likes on my screen:

```
    echo '<p class = "flames-text">';
    echo $sauce['flames'];
    echo '</p>';
```

This is how my form looks:

```
   <form method="post" action="collection.php#form-anchor1">
    <input type="image" src="./assets/img/flame.png" name="action1" value="insertVote1">
   </form>
```

Can anyone tell me why the counter doens't go up when I press for the first time?

Comment: Where are you setting the value in your HTML?

Comment: In the input;  value = "insertVote1"

Comment: I meant that value of your 'vote'.

Comment: Did you insert a default value? It could be the reason for the counter doesn't work for the first time.

Comment: As there are no parameters in that query, you could just do a `->query($sql)`

Comment: What are you expecting to get from `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` after an UPDATE query?

Comment: I have never seen a `#` used in an action `action="collection.php#form-anchor1">` Is that legal?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD You are calling insert in index.php but you send form data to coilection.php?

Comment: @Eakethet index.php = collection.php sorry!

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD Do you get "$sauce" data before or after insert?

Comment: @Eakethet after.

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD and when you look into database (phpmyadmin, or some other tool), did the value changed after first click?

Comment: @Eakethet yes it does!

Comment: @Eakethet if I refresh the page after I clicked 1 time, it counts as well..